# Is possible to apply ResponseCache on success response in .net core app 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I configured a cache profile in `Startup.cs` like

```
services.AddMvc(opts =>
  {
    opts.CacheProfiles.Add("MyCache", new CacheProfile { Duration = 60 * 60 * 24, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, VaryByQueryKeys = new[] { "url", "scene" } });
  });
```

and on action's controller, I do:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "MyCache")]
public IActionResult Search(string url, string scene)
{
    ...
    if(!found) { return NotFound(); }

    return Ok(data);
}
```

I want to cache the Ok response... Now, it caches everything and I don't wish to cache the NotFound response (I mean I want to try again). In case of success then provide the cached data.

How to do that ?

Comment: You will need to implement the Response Caching Middleware which determines when responses are cacheable, stores responses, and serves responses from cache. Give it a read... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I already setup in Startup...I need to cache only OK responses. For some reason sometimes it occur NotFound and I've to wait 1 day to expire the cache.

Comment: OK so i see since NotFound is also a Response , give this a read may be it might give you some idea on how to go about doing it https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/custom-response-caching-in-asp.net-core-with-cache-invalidation